# Detach Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, detach

After some hours debugging and trying to solve a problem, I don't found the solution. So, I hope that you can help me.

I have this little piece of code:

```
$removed = false;
if ($store->persons->contains($person)) {
    $store->persons()->detach($person);
    $removed = true;
}

var_dump($removed);
```

My problem is that I can't understand why $remove is "false" always.
If I comment the line  $store->persons()->detach($person);, everything works as expected and $removed will be "true". I can't understand why this is happening, but I hope that you can help me.

**EDIT**

```
public function removePerson(Request $request, $storeId, $personId)
{
    $store = Store::findOrFail($storeId);
    $person = Cashier::findOrFail($personId);

    $removed = false;
    if ($store->persons->contains($person)) {
        $store->persons()->detach($person);
        $removed = true;
    }

    return response()->json([
        'removed' => $removed,
    ]);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I feel like we're missing some info here.  Could you post more code?  Where are you calling cashiers?

Comment: Cashiers was an error. I added the full code of the method. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

detacth/attach method don't take full model as argument, instead they both need id of the related model so in your case you need to pass id in detach method for ex.

```
public function removePerson(Request $request, $storeId, $personId)
{
    $store = Store::findOrFail($storeId);
    $person = Cashier::findOrFail($personId);

    $removed = false;
    if ($store->persons->contains($person)) {
        $store->persons()->detach($person->id); // or $personId which ever
        $removed = true;
    }

    return response()->json([
        'removed' => $removed,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: With object or id it works fine (detach), however I don't know why the $remove doesnt becomes true.

Comment: And... In Laravel 5.3 the detach function check if the parameter is an instance of a model or collection in the first step. So you can specify a model, a collection or an array of id's as parameter.